# Wordpress showing div that does not exist in theme files?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a new blog using wordpress and I came across a strange error. in my theme file there is no

```
<div id="sliderDiv">

    <img src="images/sliderMain.png" width="1000" height="427">

</div>
```

in index.php or page.php I even look into search.php and searchpage.php but I already remove those lines from those files already but they show up all the time I could not figure out from where they are coming.those HTML lines were first used for testing purpose in all those files but I already removed them, but still showing up. I deleted them from theme editor but they are showing up. I don't know whats the problem. I also try clearing up my cache but no luck. please help

Comment: for further info here is the link of the site, 
http://warebluedemo.com/askrodavis/

Comment: Google "grep", then use that to search for that code in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a find/replace function in a text editor to search all of your theme files for that html. Any text editor - OS X or Windows - will have such functions.

Or use grep if you have a command line.